Display Excel Conditional Formatting Rules Manager - This Worksheet - Window
I want to use VBA to display the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager - This Worksheet - window. I can't record a macro because it is accessing the Excel menu.
The menu trail is: Home > Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules > This Worksheet

Any assistance will be appreciated.
Sub modConditionalFormattingCheck()
    If ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "NO Conditional Formatting found"
    Else
        MsgBox "Conditional Formatting found"
    End If
End Sub

I would like to replace the Else statement with code that display the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager.

Please, try CommandBars.ExecuteMso "ConditionalFormattingsManage"

Is this what you want? This will however show it for Current Selection. Once the window is launched, the user has to change Current Selection to This Worksheet.
Option Explicit

Sub modConditionalFormattingCheck()
    If ActiveSheet.Cells.FormatConditions.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "NO Conditional Formatting found"
    Else
        Application.Dialogs(xlDialogConditionalFormatting).Show
    End If
End Sub


Unlike some other dialogs (like e.g. Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpen).Show "*.txt", , True) showing the Conditional Formattings Manage(r) doesn't seem to accept any arguments. - btw A possibly helpful addition to the post: Dialogs enumeration
